# Can anyone identify this mystery plant growing in my vegetable garden?

Tags: identification

I put a base of compost in my vegetable garden this year which included some number of seeds from vegetables I've eaten in the past. So far I have identified a tomato and squash plant, but this one is a mystery. When it first started growing it's first leaves looked very similar to a squash plant, but as it grew it turned into this:

[Top View](http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/s720x720/538451_122629757876942_1366136107_n.jpg)

[Side View](http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/s720x720/282759_122629857876932_1831515085_n.jpg)

The leaves have a sort of hairy texture. The stalk almost looks like bamboo, the way there are sections between the leaves.

So, does anyone know the species of this plant? and will it produce edible vegetation?

Comment: Image links are currently broken. As such, this is not a very useful question for future readers who might have similar plants...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like a young [sunflower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower).  If you haven't grown them in the past, you could still end up with seeds courtesy of some squirrels or birds.  Without knowing where it came from, it's hard to say if the seeds would be edible, though again, birds and squirrels will certainly enjoy them, and honeybees will love the flowers beforehand.

Comment: Thank you! Even if I can't eat them, I do love honeybees. I will be glad to give them something to make delicious honey with!

Comment: I would add that it looks like it could be one of the taller varieties such as Mammoth. The stalk looks like it, but you'll find our soon enough!

Comment: As it turns out, it's about 5' tall. It has one large flower, and many smaller heads. Really neat!